# How to make my header looks better on Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, web

[image]

Heres my problem how can i make my header looks better

Following is the coding ...!!

1 Index.php

```
<div class="header">
<div class="headerFont"><a href="index.php">Yo! Yo! Honey Singh..!!</a>
</div>
<div class="Login">
<form>
Email :<input type="text">
Password :<input type="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login" >
<input type="button" value="register">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

2 Web-Style.css

```
.header{
 top:0;
left:0;
padding:10px;
background:#00688B;
width:100%;
height:footer-<length>;
box-shadow:2px 2x 5px #08298A;
border:1px solid black;
text-shadow:2px 2px black;
}

.header a{
 color:white;
}

.headerFont{
font-family:MATURA MT  ;
font-size:22px;
display:table-cell;
}

.Login{
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:15px;
right:50px;
}
```

3 Mobile-Style.css

```
.header {
 width: auto;
}
```

Now i need to know how can i get button like the website[PIC] -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlx09.png
How do i make button visible on mobile but not on pc borwsers ..???

Comment: So... go and make a button like that then? What exactly is the issue you're having? Do you want someone to come along and do it for you?

Comment: i know how to make a button but 
How do i make button visible on mobile but not on pc borwsers ..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the button you want on the mobile version of the website.
2. Add CSS that makes the button invisible (eg, display: none).
3. Use CSS with media queries to show the button on mobile devices.

More details here:

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score -1):

you can do this using javascript and checking the requesting browser's type.

You can detect mobile broswer's request using javascript like following.

```
if ((screen.width < 480) || (screen.height < 480)) {
    location.replace('/mobile/');
   /*Get buggon element by id and show it else hide it*/
  }
```

or may be you can use following javascript to detent mobile browser and then hide the button.

https://github.com/miohtama/detectmobile.js

Comment: To use different layouts in differently sized viewports, media queries and CSS are the modern way.

Comment: it depends Mr, Jukka if you do not want to do too much Javascript is not good?

Comment: media queries are not Javascript!